# How to do this in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this situation:

I have a range of columns. And I want to set indicator to '1' if any of the matching codes appear in that range. example:

```
C D E F G H   M
1 2 3 4 5 6   if any value in range C1:H1 lie between 1-4 then 1 else 0
```

Say Column C1:H1, I want to create column M1(an indicator) such that any of codes say (1,2,3,4) Appear in range C1:H1 its value is set to 1 else 0

Comment: Do you really want the range to be C1:H1 and the formula to be in G1?

Comment: Updated the column to a different column, but I think u got the point

Answer (score -1):

You can add an IF function to cells in column G to do this:

```
=IF(OR(C1="1",D1="2",E1="3"),"1","0")
```

This currently only caters for 3 columns, so add additional arguments to the OR function, if you want to incorporate additional columns. All you then need to do is amend the "1", "2" and "3" etc for your codes and amend the ranges for your dataset.

Comment: I dont want to code so many columns manually.. as there are around 30 columns.. Can I select range?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming cells A1:A4 contain the values 1,2,3,4, an array formula that checks whether any of these values appear in the range C1:H1 is

```
=OR(EXACT(A$1:A$4, C1:H1))*1
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/compare-cell-contents-HP003056130.aspx#BMcompare_one_value_to_a_list_of_values for a formula that does something similar.

Comment: @pnuts I've added a comment to the question to seek clarification.

Comment: Is there anyway, I can insert the values for comparison like 28:40, instead of manually entering them in columns A28:A40?